# MFMailComposerViewController Memory leak

Tags: iphone, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

In my app whenever i send email with an attachment. The `MFMailComposer` does not release the memory after sending the email. The size of the data that i am attaching is around 2-4 MB. How i can solve this issue so that i do not get memory leak after sending email.

Comment: Are you displaying the mail composer properly? Maybe you are leaking the whole controller. Try to reproduce the problem on a [small code sample](http://sscce.org/) and show us that.

Comment: Please show your code strip where the leak occours!

Comment: show Your code first then only we can determine where the leak is?